# .NET Core Identity doesn't refresh auth cookie for static files and throws 500 error

Tags: angular, cookies, .net-core, static-files, asp.net-core-identity

I have .NET Core Web API app with Angular 2 on client-side.
I setup .NET Core Identity with the following options in `Startup.cs`:

```
options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;                                              
options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
options.SecurityStampValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 100;
options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14);
options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/api/signin/signin";
options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LogoutPath = "/api/signin/signout";
options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
```

So,

1. User is logged in - auth cookie is set.
2. 60 seconds later - calls to **API/*** end-points update this cookie to a new value .. so calls work
3. However calls to **HTML/JS** files do not update the cookie - they continue to use the previous cookie which now is presumably not tied to the session which then means we get the **500** error as it can't do something.
4. Loading any **API/*** end-point updates the cookie and **HTML/JS** files work again.

So in short - the issue seems to be related to auth cookie not being refreshed for all the static content. And it just works fine without any cookie, when user is logged out.

How can I fix that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to docs section [`Introduction to working with static files in ASP.NET Core`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files#static-file-authorization):

> The static file module provides **no** authorization checks.

Solution for this (from the same article):

> - Store them outside of `wwwroot` and any directory accessible to the static file middleware **and**
> - Serve them through a controller action, returning a [`FileResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.aspx) where authorization is applied

So basically you have to either make some requests for your API constantly to update the session or create some dummy controller for static files.

Comment: I can't understand, then why do we need built-in folder "wwwroot"? For apps without authorization? I want to static files always work without changing cookie or anything else.

Comment: It is a built-in folder for your files. ASP.NET team made a decision that the static files by default do not need the authorized requests.

Comment: Okay, then why don't static files work with authorization? Why do I see 500 error instead of access to static file even if cookie is changed?

Comment: I think that's because the error is come from code which do validation the cookie. I think you should consider to fire an issue on github to get some official advice for your solution